# How to optimize our MySQL select/update performance?

Tags: mysql

We have a very big table(20,000,000+ rows) include these two columns : `create_date`, `id`.

I have already create indexes for them, now I want to create partition for this table.

The most frequently used SQLs are:

```
select sum(x) from ttt group by create_time;
update ttt set x = 123 where id = 'ididid';
```

What's the best way to partition ?

Comment: 2000W ? 2000 000 rows?

Comment: @mpm, Sorry, 200,000,000 rows